# Ruler/Protractor tool - change snapping values for easier snapping to vertices?

Tags: modeling, measurement

I wanted to use the Ruler/Protractor tool to measure some length for an environment scene.

Is there a way to change the snapping values of the Ruler/Protractor tool?
or is there a way to easily snap one side of teh ruler to a selected vertice?

when I try to use the Ctrl+Drag, the snapping wanders of the vertice which I want it to snap to, which is really frustrating.

EDIT;
using the tool while in edit mode, this is often the result.

[image]

Comment: Currently, Ctrl+drag works best in Wireframe mode.

Comment: Actually, I did experience such thing right before your post. :) I was going to report this by that time. Now I think maybe the current snap doesn't support quite well for poles or edges in some case, even in Wireframe mode.

Comment: do you think that this unwanted behaviour of the snapping tool would be worth an bug report?

Comment: I found a related [**commit**](https://projects.blender.org/scm/viewvc.php?view=rev&root=bf-blender&revision=56287). I don't know if it helps. Technically, it doesn't work as well as expected, so I think it can be worth an mention. :)

Comment: The snapping behavior is hard-coded, but could be changed to favor vertices even more. Best talk to ideasman_42!

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to measure simlpe edges I would use the **Mesh Display** Tools in the Propertys Panel of 3D View.(Press N to diplay)

First switch to edit mode. Then activate Edge Info>Length:
[image: Mesh Diplay | Edge Length]

Then it displays the the length of the selected edge or what else you want in the 3D View.

Answer (score 0):

The first click of the ruler does not seem to snap to the point you wanted.
Snap the second measure point to the location you want and readjust the first (starting) point by left clicking and snapping it to your starting location.
The measurement points can be moved and snapped anytime after being initially set.